# $wpdb->insert inserting only f character in custom table

Tags: wpdb

I have made a quick `$wpdb->insert` function that adds content with an AJAX function.

The goal is to insert the form data into a table.

Here is my Javascript function calling the ajax:

```
$(".modal__form").submit(function(e){

            e.preventDefault();

            $.post(

                ajaxurl,
                {
                    'action': 'add_to_newsletter',
                    'param': $(this).serialize()
                },
                function(response){

                    if(response == 'success') {

                        $('.modal__form').hide();
                        $('.modal__box .text__success').show();
                    }
                }
            );

        });
```

The form data in headers can be printed as :

```
action: add_to_newsletter
param: firstname=FIRSTNAME&lastname=LASTNAME&email=EMAIL%40DOMAIN.COM&type=TYPE
```

On my function, I have this :

```
function add_to_newsletter() {

    global $wpdb;

    $table = $wpdb->prefix.'newsletter';
    $param = $_POST['param'];

    if($wpdb->insert($table, array(

        'firstname' => $param['firstname'],
        'lastname' => $param['lastname'],
        'email' => $param['email'],
        'ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

        ),
        array( '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')
    )) {

        var_dump($wpdb);
        echo 'success';

    }
    else {

        $wpdb->print_error();
    }



    die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_add_to_newsletter', 'add_to_newsletter' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_add_to_newsletter', 'add_to_newsletter' );
```

The problem is that I only got strange things on the database when posted.

Here is the `var_dump()` return.

```sql
"INSERT INTO 'actz_newsletter' ('firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'ip') VALUES ('f', 'f', 'f', '::1')"
```

Anyone ever expected something similar? I am clueless about my research.

Comment: First, I would either pass separate parameters or `wp_json_encode` the parameters instead of serializing. Then you need to decode once you receive them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_POST['param']` is a string, you can not treat it like an array. That's why only `f` characters are inserted.

You have two options, prepare data as an array in javascript or parse the string to array on the PHP side.

Sample code for 2nd option:

```
$table = $wpdb->prefix.'newsletter';

// 'firstname=FIRSTNAME&lastname=LASTNAME&email=EMAIL%40DOMAIN.COM&type=TYPE'
$input = explode( '&', $_POST['param'] );
$param = array_reduce( $input, function( &$carry, $item ) {
            $parts = explode('=', $item);
            $carry[ $parts[0] ] = urldecode( $parts[1] );
            return $carry;
        }, 
        array()
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the observation. That was indeed the problem of my request. My data was passed as a string. Your code worked and I will be good to continue my job from there.